# jQuery - cannot get col number of a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to get a column number of a td by selecting the td by its class name. But it always returns -1. What is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Et46D/)

HTML

```
<table >
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td >apple</td><td class="current">banana</td><td>cherry</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS

```
   console.log($("td.current:first").parent().parent().children().index($(this)));
```

Comment: What're you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the variant of [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) that does not take any arguments, to get the index based on its sibling elements

```
console.log($("td.current:first").index());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5wXnG/)

Answer (score 2):

Simply do:

```
console.log($("td").index($("td.current:first")));
```

As you have it, `$(this)` is pointing to the `window` object, and not the scope you think it is, which has not been defined in the context of the call.

Also note that `index()` works thusly: `collection.index(member)`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't neet to get parent then parent, Simply do this

```
$("td.current:first").index();
```